# use `getValueFromEvent` in ant design Form

Tags: reactjs, antd

i wanted to know how to use ant image picker (or any other component) in ant design form.
and if possible i wanted to know how getValueFromEvent will be called and how to change it to make in work.

here is my sample. i think its pretty straight:

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-lfk7k?file=/index.js

this section should be trigged in some way.

```
const normFile = (e) => {
  console.log("Upload event:", e);
  if (Array.isArray(e)) {
    return e;
  }
  return e && e.fileList;
};
```

the only thing i'm not understanding is how the event will be trigged?
i'll be thankful for any document or link or ...

Comment: the code sample you shared uses single file upload. can you explain what it is youre trying to achieve with this "normFile" function

Comment: @poeticGeek actually i copied it from antd document. i dont need the array part. i just want to use that image crop component.

Comment: I've added an answer that should help you. If youre not attached to antd, I'd recommend react-uploady. Its a lot easier to use. I've blogged about using it with a cropping library here: https://medium.com/swlh/adding-crop-before-upload-in-react-22dfcf3a95b7

Answer (score 1):

In your code you use 'customRequest' documented as such: "Override for the default xhr behavior allowing for additional customization and ability to implement your own XMLHttpRequest"

So, you'd need to implement your own upload behavior. If that's not what you meant, id suggest using the needed props such as 'action' ('method', etc) to specify where the file should be uploaded to.

Comment: my problem is something else. the form work great if i remove the imgcrop tag. i just want to set form values in some way.

Comment: which values? your example only has the one upload field inside the form. note that antd-img-crop will upload the result of the crop that was done to the file you selected

Comment: yea of course i want updated value. but antd-img-crop do not pass value to the form.
the form get value from child element, now that imgcrop is the child the value won't pass.

Comment: from what I can see (https://github.com/nanxiaobei/antd-img-crop/blob/master/src/index.jsx) img-crop will change the file that was selected with the result of the crop using the <Upload> beforeUpload. You dont need to do anything beyond that. How are you checking that it "isnt passing"?

Comment: ```onFinish={(e) => {console.log(e); }}```
this part will log the final value of the form and the section of my image is null

Comment: I don think this is the way to test it. Especially since youre setting 'customRequest' on the Upload component and calling onSuccess without any parameter... See documentation on customRequest: https://github.com/react-component/upload#customrequest

Answer (score 1):

Below trick should work to set value to Form.Item for Upload inside Image Crop:

```
import {
    Form,
    Upload,
} from 'antd';
import ImgCrop from 'antd-img-crop';
import axios from "axios";

const Upload = (props) => {
    const [form] = Form.useForm();

    const uploadImage = async options => {

        const { onSuccess, onError, file, onProgress, category } = options;

        const fmData = new FormData();
        const config = {
            headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
            onUploadProgress: event => {
                const percent = Math.floor((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
                onProgress({ percent: (event.loaded / event.total) * 100 }, file);
            }
        };
        fmData.append("file", file);
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(
                `${API_DOMAIN}/upload`,
                fmData,
                config
            );
            onSuccess("ok", res);
            form.setFieldsValue({ photo: res.data.link })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Eroor: ", err);
            const error = new Error("Some error");
            onError({ err });
        }
    }
    return (
        <Form
            {...formItemLayout}
            form={form}
            name="form_name"
            onFinish={onFinish}
            scrollToFirstError
        >

            <Form.Item
                label="Photo"
                name="photo"
            >
                <ImgCrop rotate>
                    <Upload
                        name={'file'}
                        customRequest={uploadImage}
                        listType="picture-card"
                        onChange={onChange}
                        fileList={fileList}
                        onPreview={onPreview}
                        accept={"image/*"}
                    >
                        {fileList.length < 1 && '+ Upload'}
                    </Upload>
                </ImgCrop>
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use ImgCrop "antd-img-crop" with ant Form and Upload widget, and get the value with getFieldsValue() I made this code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import BasePanel          from '@/containers/BasePanel';
import BaseFormComponent  from '@/formcomponents/BaseFormComponent';
import { Upload, Form, Button, Input, Select } from 'antd';
import { UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import ImgCrop from 'antd-img-crop';
const { Option } = Select;

const CroppedInput = ({ value = {}, onChange }) => {
    const [fotos, setfotos] = useState([]);

    const triggerChange = (changedValue) => {
        onChange?.({
            fotos,
            ...value,
            ...changedValue,
        });
    };

    const onChange2 = (file) => {
        console.log(file);
        setfotos(file);

        triggerChange({
            fotos: file.fileList,
        });
    };

    return (
        <ImgCrop>
            <Upload listType="picture-card" maxCount={3} onChange={e => onChange2(e)}>
                <UploadOutlined />
            </Upload>
        </ImgCrop>
    );
};


class FormMultiImage extends BaseFormComponent{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.checkValidator = this.checkValidator.bind(this);
    }

    checkValidator (_, value) {
        if (value !== undefined && value.fotos.length > 0) {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
        return Promise.reject(new Error('Por favor seleccione una imagen'));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Form.Item
                    label={"label"}
                    name={"name"}
                    rules={[
                        {
                            validator: this.checkValidator,
                        },
                    ]}
                >
                    <CroppedInput />
                </Form.Item>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default FormMultiImage;
```

And call it in your form

```
<Form>
    <FormMultiImage />
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a custom Component wrapping both `ImgCrop` and `Upload` and passing all props to the inner `Upload` component.

Below is the TypeScript code with React hooks

```js
const ImgCropUpload: React.FC<UploadProps> = (props) => (
    <ImgCrop>
        <Upload {...props} />
    </ImgCrop>
);
```

Now you can use it inside `Form.Item`:

```js
<Form.Item name="image" label="Image">
    <ImgCropUpload action={url}>
        <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />} loading={uploading}>Upload image</Button>
    </ImgCropUpload>
</Form.Item>
```